# What's new in Xcode previous versions?

Tags: xcode, readme

Apple previously published a “What’s new in Xcode 7” information page at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html

…but now that URL reports an error, “Sorry, that page cannot be found.”.

How can a developer learn or relearn the various features added into Xcode?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Apple has now relocated that information into an archive section of their web site.

See the page, [*What’s New in Xcode - Archive*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017029), for links to:

- [New Features in Xcode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_7_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015242-SW1)
- [New Features in Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW1)
- [New Features in Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1)
- [New Features in Xcode 4](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_4_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016147-SW1)

For the current version 8, see:

- [What’s New in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004626)
- [Xcode 8](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
  (a brochure page with tabs for additional info)